# Change folders path of gallery with Jquery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, gallery, fotorama

i'm trying to make some kind of interactive gallery for my portfolio. My code includes a jquery gallery plugin (fotorama) and some ajax that works "partially".

The "Fotorama" plugin works with img tags, so i just have to include a list of img tags and the plugin does the rest while the AJAX part its suposed to make that image list dynamically from a directory path.

The problem comes when i want to change the string of the variable "dir" when i click on another album. it looks like the string changes efficiently because i did some tests with alert(dir) but the AJAX doesn't recognize that change.

```
<div id="galeria" class="galeria">
    <div class="close-button"><img src="img/iconos/close2.svg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs"   data-width="100%" data-height="100%"   data-arrows="true" data-click="true" data-swipe="true">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var dir = "";
                var fileextension = ".jpg";
                //Album 1
                $("#comision-btn").click(function() {
                    dir = "img/galerias/ilustracion/comisiones/";
                    alert(dir);
                    $(".galeria").slideDown("fast");
                });
                //Album 2
                $("#concept-btn").click(function() {
                    dir = "img/galerias/ilustracion/concept/";
                    alert(dir);
                    $(".galeria").slideDown("fast");      
                });

                $.ajax({

                //Image List from Directory
                url: dir,
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
                        var filename = this.href.replace(window.location, "");
                        $(".fotorama").append($("<img src=" + dir + filename + "></img>"));
                    });
                }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>            
</div>
```

Here you can see the code "working":
https://seralprueba.000webhostapp.com/

What is wrong with this code? is there a better way to acchieve this?

Note: If i write one of the albums path (for example: img/galerias/ilustracion/comisiones/ in the part where i declare the **dir** variable, the fotorama's plugin works, but i still can't change that direction when i click on another option.